# Categorize an array of strings and add its elements to different parts of an object

Tags: java

I have an array of strings called `empList` that looks like this

```
10000  
72.2  
45.6  
55.3  
-1  
10001  
19.3  
-1  
10002  
13.5  
14.6  
-1
```

And I want to add these data to a complex object `Employee`, with the definition below:

```
class Employee{
    public int ID;
    public List<Float> results;
}
```

and the criteria are:
For each item in empList:

If `Integer.parseInt(item) >=10000` -> add to Employee.ID;

The following items are parsed as floats, and add to `results` of the current Employee object, until,

`Float.parseFloat(item) == -1` -> done assigning values to this Employee, go to the next Employee.

according to these rules, I will get 3 objects out of the string array. What is the fastest way to do it?

---

Update: what I've got so far:

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i=0; i<empList.size(); i++){
        if (Integer.parseInt(empList.get(i))>=10000) 
            employees.add(new Employee(Integer.parseInt(empList.get(i))));
 // let's say Employee has a constructor that accepts an int and assign it as ID 
        }
```

which initiates the 3 objects with their IDs, and then

```
int populated = 0;
for (int j=0; j<empList.size(); j++){
    if (Integer.parseInt(empList.get(j)) <10000 
         && Integer.parseInt(empList.get(j)) !=1
         && !empList.get(j).isEmpty()
         )
        employees.get(populated).results.add(Float.parseFloat(empList.get(j)));
    else if (Integer.parseInt(empList.get(j)) !=1)
        populated++;
}
```

But the above add everything to the first Employee, instead of jumping to the second Employee after the `-1`.

Comment: Fastest way is to write code and have the computer do it for you.

Comment: @PM77-1 hold on I am posting my code promptly

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono updated

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(empList.get(j)) !=1` ... and you compare that with 1 instead of -1, because ....? And your first loop doesn't even care about -1, it just checks for `>=10000`

Comment: @Tom ok I see it now. Thank you. Do you want to post an answer? Otherwise I will close this thread.

Comment: Delete it, since it was just a typo. It won't help anyone else in the future.

Comment: Use a scanner on your string

Comment: You Employee class needs a constructor.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson i have assumed the class has a constructor. What do you use the scanner for?

Comment: I missed the array of strings. I thought it said string that's why I used scanner.  Lol

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want :

> TestIndex.class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestIndex {

    class Employee{
        public int ID;
        public List<Float> results;

        Employee(int id, List<Float> extractResults) {
            ID = id;
            results = extractResults;
        }

        public void print(){
            System.out.println("Employee ID: " + ID);
            System.out.print("results: ");
            for (Float f : results) {
              System.out.print(f + " "); 
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    private int parseEmployee(float[] array, int index, List<Employee> employees) {
        List<Float> extractResults = new ArrayList<Float>();
        int id = (int)array[index];
        for(int subIndex = index + 1; subIndex < array.length; subIndex++) {
            if(array[subIndex] == -1 || array[subIndex] > 10000) {
                index = subIndex;
                break;
            } 
            extractResults.add(array[subIndex]);
        }
        employees.add(new Employee(id, extractResults));
        return index;
    }

    TestIndex()  {
        float[] array = {
                10000,  
                72.2F,  
                45.6F,  
                55.3F,  
                -1,  
                10001,  
                19.3F,  
                -1,  
                10002,  
                13.5F,  
                14.6F,  
                -1  
        };
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        for(Integer index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
            if(array[index] >= 10000) {
                index = parseEmployee(array, index, employees);
            }
        }
        for(Employee employee : employees) {
            employee.print();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestIndex();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The main issue would be the faulty check condition to populate your results, as pointed out by the comment on your post. 
Additionally sort parts have been optimised in this code as

- it doesn't parse the array twice: instead it chops the data processing up in parts to gradually create your objects.
- by building the objects gradually, it avoids an empty collection check
- the object internal subIndex offset is fed back into the primary parsing loop, so that it can immediately start with the processing of the next `Employee` object

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I thought about it. My issue is that you didn't explain anything - just "Here's code".

Comment: You can see what is wrong by comparing my posted code with your code.   The main issue would be the faulty check condition to populate your results, as pointed out by the comment on your post.  Additionally this code doesn't parse the array twice.  Instead it chops the data processing up in parts to gradually create your objects.

Comment: #1, I'm not the OP. #2, That information should be in the answer, not a comment.

Comment: Edited the post with additional explanation.  Is it clear for you now?

Comment: We need to ask the OP that question, not me.

Comment: @Filip Is it possible to combine 2 for loops and make it faster?

Comment: @DylanChensky which loops would you like to combine?  The primary (general data array) loop and the internal parseEmployee loop are already combined.  If you are talking about combining the print loop (which was just added for clarity of execution), yes it can be embedded in the internal parseEmployee method